# How to find the resultant of two forces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors

I got this question in a assignment and haven't been able to figure out how to get to the correct result.

> *A force of 6 newtons and a force of 10 newtons can be combine to form
>   a resultant of what magnitude?*
>
> *Ans ( 8 newtons )*

I though this would simply be the sum of these forces, but it wasn't.

Comment: If the forces were in the same direction, then it would be 16. If they were in opposite directions, it would be 4. Now you figure out what it would be if they were at right angles.

Comment: The question is incomplete without knowledge of the direction the forces are applied. As Mike has already stated with the answer provided one may attempt to intrapolate the direction but it really ought to be part of the question in the first place.

Comment: I'm closing this question as _off-topic,_ because the current question formulation (v2) is incomplete if the answer is 8N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only asked about the magnitude of the resultant, the directions of the vectors are only relative. So we can locate the first vector anywhere we want.  So:

Draw a line 10 units long along the x-axis, starting at the origin.

Using the endpoint of this line, at $(10,0)$, as the center, draw a circle of radius 6 units.

The line from the origin to ***any*** point on this circle represents all the possible magnitudes of the resultant of the two given vectors.  All values between $4$ and $16$ are possible.

Comment: Ahh ok, so there could be a set of correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Forces are vectors, which have magnitude and direction. Is the direction of the vectors known? If yes, then you need to resolve the forces into components along a common coordinate system, and add the components. In the end, the resultant components will give you the resultant magnitude also.

Comment: I only was given the information above. Could the problem be in one dimension?